# Netcode: Implementing Audio/Video Transmission Between Unity Apps?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, augmented-reality, audio-streaming, multiplayer

I'm developing a Unity application and need guidance on implementing audio and video transmission between apps using Netcode. Specifically, I'm exploring ways to extend host/client communication to facilitate the exchange of AR-generated content. Any insights or resources on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

I've been working with Unity Netcode for host/client communication, aiming to facilitate the exchange of audio and video between AR applications. I expected seamless integration, but encountered challenges. Seeking guidance on overcoming these obstacles and optimizing the implementation.